# VBA Compile error: else without if

Tags: vba, ms-access, if-statement

I'm getting the

> Compile error: else without if

error on the first `ElseIf` in the following code block. As far as I'm aware the structure is correct, I have tried removing the white space and indentation with no luck. What am I missing?

```
Dim notesSQL As QueryDef
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Column, targetCell As String
Set notesSQL = db.QueryDefs("Export_Table_Notes_Filter")
Set rs = notesSQL.OpenRecordset()

If Insp_Template_No.Value = "Hazardous Area Equipment Detailed Inspection (Ex 'I' Ex 'iD' Ex 'nL)" Then
    Column = "b"
    Row = 16

    Do Until rs.EOF
        targetCell = (Column & Row)
        With wsheet
        .Range(targetCell).CopyFromRecordset rs
        End With

        targetCell = (count + 1)
ElseIf Insp_Template_No.Value = "Hazardous Area Equipment Visual Inspection (Ex 'd' and Ex 'e')" Then
    Column = "c"
    Row = 15

    Do Until rs.EOF
        targetCell = (Column & Row)
        With wsheet
        .Range(targetCell).CopyFromRecordset rs
        End With

        targetCell = (count + 1)
ElseIf Insp_Template_No.Value = "Hazardous Area Equipment Close Inspection (Ex 'I' Ex 'iD' Ex 'nL)" Then
    Column = "b"
    Row = 15

    Do Until rs.EOF
        targetCell = (Column & Row)
        With wsheet
        .Range(targetCell).CopyFromRecordset rs
        End With

        targetCell = (count + 1)
Else
    MsgBox ("Unrecognised inspection template")
End If

Loop
```

Comment: You need to close your `Do` with `Loop` before using `ElseIf` and you will probably also need to use `rs.MoveNext` if you dont want to end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: It is the `Do Loop` before the second `ElseIf` that is missing `Loop`.

Comment: Aghhh so simple! thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire loop is redundant, since `.CopyFromRecordset` moves the recordset to `.EOF`. Remove it. Furthermore, the code can be improved by using a `SELECT ... CASE`

```
Dim notesSQL As QueryDef
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Column, targetCell As String
Set notesSQL = Db.QueryDefs("Export_Table_Notes_Filter")
Set rs = notesSQL.OpenRecordset()

Row = 0
Select Case Insp_Template_No.Value 
Case "Hazardous Area Equipment Detailed Inspection (Ex 'I' Ex 'iD' Ex 'nL)"
    Column = "b"
    Row = 16
Case "Hazardous Area Equipment Visual Inspection (Ex 'd' and Ex 'e')" 
    Column = "c"
    Row = 15
Case "Hazardous Area Equipment Close Inspection (Ex 'I' Ex 'iD' Ex 'nL)" 
    Column = "b"
    Row = 15
Case Else
    MsgBox ("Unrecognised inspection template")
End Select

If Row > 0 Then
   targetCell = (Column & Row)
   wsheet.Range(targetCell).CopyFromRecordset rs
End If
```

Comment: This is perfect. I'm new to coding, and haven't used `SELECT... CASE` yet. After reading your answer I will be replacing a lot of my "Redundant" loops. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The whole thing can be greatly simplified by moving the `rs` loop outside of the `If..Else..Endif`.

```
Dim notesSQL As QueryDef
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Column, targetCell As String
Set notesSQL = Db.QueryDefs("Export_Table_Notes_Filter")
Set rs = notesSQL.OpenRecordset()

Row = 0
If Insp_Template_No.Value = "Hazardous Area Equipment Detailed Inspection (Ex 'I' Ex 'iD' Ex 'nL)" Then
    Column = "b"
    Row = 16
ElseIf Insp_Template_No.Value = "Hazardous Area Equipment Visual Inspection (Ex 'd' and Ex 'e')" Then
    Column = "c"
    Row = 15
ElseIf Insp_Template_No.Value = "Hazardous Area Equipment Close Inspection (Ex 'I' Ex 'iD' Ex 'nL)" Then
    Column = "b"
    Row = 15
Else
    MsgBox ("Unrecognised inspection template")
End If

If Row > 0 Then
    Do Until rs.EOF
        targetCell = (Column & Row)
        With wsheet
        .Range(targetCell).CopyFromRecordset rs
        End With

        targetCell = (Count + 1)
        rs.Movenext
    Loop
End If
```

Comment: A further improvement might be a `SELECT ... CASE` instead of `IF ... ELSEIF` when comparing the same variable to multiple values

Comment: Same issue with @braX 's code, the inclusion of the `rs.movenext`  is causing  `Run-time error '3021' No Current Record`. The refactor looks much better however.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code. Your loops are not set up correctly, and you are missing `rs.MoveNext`. Try it like this:

```
Dim notesSQL As QueryDef
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Column, targetCell As String
Set notesSQL = Db.QueryDefs("Export_Table_Notes_Filter")
Set rs = notesSQL.OpenRecordset()

If Insp_Template_No.Value = "Hazardous Area Equipment Detailed Inspection (Ex 'I' Ex 'iD' Ex 'nL)" Then
    Column = "b"
    Row = 16

    Do Until rs.EOF
        targetCell = (Column & Row)
        With wsheet
        .Range(targetCell).CopyFromRecordset rs
        End With

        targetCell = (Count + 1)
        rs.Movenext
    Loop
ElseIf Insp_Template_No.Value = "Hazardous Area Equipment Visual Inspection (Ex 'd' and Ex 'e')" Then
    Column = "c"
    Row = 15

    Do Until rs.EOF
        targetCell = (Column & Row)
        With wsheet
        .Range(targetCell).CopyFromRecordset rs
        End With

        targetCell = (Count + 1)
        rs.Movenext
    Loop
ElseIf Insp_Template_No.Value = "Hazardous Area Equipment Close Inspection (Ex 'I' Ex 'iD' Ex 'nL)" Then
    Column = "b"
    Row = 15

    Do Until rs.EOF
        targetCell = (Column & Row)
        With wsheet
        .Range(targetCell).CopyFromRecordset rs
        End With

        targetCell = (Count + 1)
        rs.Movenext
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox ("Unrecognised inspection template")
End If
```

Comment: Thank you @braX , this is perfect.

Comment: Actually spoke to soon. Adding rs.movenext in each loop causes a "Run-time error '3021' No Current Record" error. Without the rs.movenext the code appears to work fine. (However I am concerned about this infinite loop you mentioned!)

Comment: I recommend using the code from the other answer. It is much better.